# Xcode font needed

Tags: xcode, xcode5, xcode4.5, xcode6

[image]I am using Xcode 6 for development.Recently while going through the some posts in web,I 
    saw some new look of Xcode.Here I attached screen of that.I am not sure of that font that exist
    in the Xcode that I mentioned.I want to use that font in my Xcode.If anyone knows please let me 
    know.

Comment: It the new font of OS X Yosemite

Comment: Thank you.I will get in touch with Yosemite update.